# Gmail api with workload identity federation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client, workload-identity

I have created a workload identity pool with a third-party (auth0) provider. I have configured my service account with a domain-wide delegation and have enabled GMAIL API as well.
I could generate STS token successfully but while executing mail client it's giving me an error.
Previously with the service account approach, I used to provide email as subject to delegate access to the service account.
Since I am using workload identity (to eliminate keys), I am getting an error "precondition check failed".

What are the limitations of the Workload Identity federation?
Can we access user data(mail/drive files) if we have enabled domain-wide delegation for the service accounts being used for the Workload identity federation?

I am attaching snippet here :

```
 async function main2(){
     const authClient = google.auth.ExternalAccountClient.fromJSON(jsonConfig);


     authClient.scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 
           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];

      const gmail = google.gmail({
         auth: authClient,
         version: 'v1'
       });

      const response = await gmail.users.getProfile({
          userId : 'abc@domain.com'
          });

  console.log(response);
}
```

JSON config contains client library config.
I am using the node.js client library.

My use case is to take these configs from clients(mostly orgs) to access sheets, drive, email of their users.

Comment: I do not think you can. How will you set the **subject**? However, I have not tried to do this.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes; I won't be able to pass the subject. I was hoping if there was any way to do so.
I tried a workaround. I signed JWT using the above method which delegates service account authority to a new sub. And then created a post-call using that signed JWT JSON to retrieve an access token. I was able to access the required data using this way. But I was hoping for any proper solution was there.

await iamCredentialsClient.projects.serviceAccounts.signJwt({{.... })

I used this to generate signed JWT.
I don't know if this is right way to do that.

Comment: Yes, using signJwt is the correct method. I often recommend that method when the private key is not available. I just have not tested that with Workload Identity Federation.

Comment: @JohnHanley yep, Thanks for the input. I had confused if I am going with the right solution.
Thanks for the help.

P.S: This was my first question StackOverflow

Comment: You picked a challenging topic. Post an answer with your solution. There is a lot of interest in both Workload Identity Federation and Domain Wide Delegation separately and together.

Comment: @knucklehead, any update on how you got this to work? I've run into the same issue and could use some guidance getting this to work.